# Какая разница между `export default foo` и `export { foo as default }`?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Очень прошу помочь никак не могу понять различие между

```
export default foo
```

И

```
 export { foo as default }
```

Какая между ними разница ?

Где и в каких случаях какую лучше использовать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начну из отрывка книги **Кайла Симпсона ES6 & Не только**.

Давайте сравним два фрагмента

```
function foo(..){
   // . .
}
export default foo;
```

Второй:

```
function foo(..){
   // . .
}
export {foo as default}
```

В первом случае вы экспортируете привязку в значение функционального выражения, а не идентификатор `foo`.Другими словами,`export default ..` преобразовывает выражение.Если позднее присвоить функцию `foo`другому значению внутри модуля, процедура импорта все равно будет показывать изначально экспортированную функцию.

Вернемся ко второму фрагменту:

```
function foo(..){
   //..
}
export {foo as default}
```

Здесь привязка экспорта по умолчанию на самом деле к идентификатору `foo` , а не к его значению ,то есть вы получаете ранее описанное поведение (в частности, если позднее вы поменяете значение `foo`, обновитсья и значение на стороне импорта).

Будьте крайне осторожны с этим небольшим подводным камнем в синтаксисие экспорта по умолчанию ,особенно если логическая схема требует обновлять экспортируемые значение.Если вы не планируете этого делать,прекрасно подойдет вариант `export default ..`.В противном случае следует пользоватсья вариантом `export {..as default}`.И не забудьте снабдить ваш код комментариями,поясняющими ваши намерения!

Если этот отрывок не понятно приведу пример с кодом из песочницы тогда все будет яснее.

У нас есть 3 JS файла

**another.js**

```
export const bla = 5;
export * from "./sub";
```

**sub.js**

```
export const bla = 3,
  foo = 4;
```

**index.js (основной)**

```
import * as another from "./another";
```

В таком случае если мы напишем то получем следующее

```
console.log(another);  // { bla: 5, foo: 4 }
```

Переменная **bla** присвоилось новое значение с 3 на 5 внутри **another.js**.

Но если написать вот так внутри `another.js`

```
export const bla = 5;
export * from "./sub";
export { bla as default } from "./sub";
```

То уже будет три значение третий который default и который нельзя потом изменить внутри основного файла

```
console.log(another);  // {bla: 5, default: 3, foo: 4}
```

Если внутри index.js мы попытаемся сделать вот так

```
import * as another from "./another";

console.log(another); //  {default: 3, bla: 80, foo: 4}
another.bla = 80;
```

Все будет работать

Но если попытаемся изменить default то будет ошибка

```
import * as another from "./another";

another.default= 80;
```

**TypeError: Cannot set property default of # which has only a getter**

Вот  [**тут**](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-dew-w3foj) можете все потестировать